# why zsh adds "%" at the end of my output

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

i'm using zsh on my mac (oh-my-zsh) and i don't understand why at the end of my output there is always this character: "%"

[image]

If i don't put export TERM="xterm-256color" in my ~/.zshrc i haven't that character:

[image]

Comment: [What does the percentage sign in zsh shell come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69708348) is a good canonical duplicate for questions about code whose output didn't end with a newline, where ZSH's behaviour worked as intended to highlight this with a `%`.  This question seems to be about that happening on an unconventional terminal that doesn't work the way ZSH expects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually a bold `%` (or `#` for root) with reversed colors is used to signify a "partial" line in the output. That is a line, which is not terminated with a newline character.

As it seems to depend on the value of `TERM` I suspect an incompatibility between that value and the settings of terminal emulator. Contrary to the warning shown in your second screenshot, you actually should **not** set `TERM` in your `~/.zshrc` (or anywhere inside the shell session). `TERM` should always be set by the terminal emulator itself. Its value (in conjunction with the `terminfo` *terminal capability data base*) tells the shell and other programs, which features a terminal emulator supports and how to use them. If the value is changed in the shell, the terminal emulator will not know about it. This may lead to programs sending control codes the terminal emulator does not understand correctly or at all.

In order to change the value of `TERM` you should change it in the terminal emulator settings. According to the [iTerm 2 FAQ](https://www.iterm2.com/faq.html) the settings is to be found at *Preferences->Profiles->Terminal->Report Terminal Type*.

Comment: [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582) on unix.SE covers the details of how it prints a `%` and spaces to line-wrap or not before a `\r`.  Maybe on some terminals, things happen differently than ZSH expects, and the `%` ends up on a different line.

Answer (score 2):

I personally placed `export PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` inside my `~/.zprofile` and hide the character.

[image]