# What does the percentage sign in zsh shell come from?

Tags: c, zsh

When I run this piece of code (from a tutorial to binary security), I always get an "%" in my zsh shell. Where do these percentage signs come from and how to get rid of them?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char buf[256];
  memcpy(buf, argv[1],strlen(argv[1]));

  printf("%s", buf);
}


% ./a.out 234
234%
% ./a.out 23466
23466%
% ./a.out 2
2%
```

Comment: It is the prompt ( $PS1) And historically, it stems from csh.

Comment: You should end your `printf()` format with a newline, or use `puts(buf);` instead.  The `%` is the prompt from the shell which appears after your output which doesn't have a newline at the end.  Get into the habit of ensuring that outputs end with newlines — it will save you lots of angst over the years.  (You didn't mention that you hit return after seeing the `%` at the end of the output and before the next command, but I believe you did, unless `zsh` does something really tricky.)

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to hardcode 256 here. You already call `strlen` to get the string's length, so use that (plus one)!

Comment: It comes from *undefined behavior* as your `buf` is not terminated. I don't know how no one, including the accepted answer pointed that out (newline is essential too though).

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582

Comment: The `%` immediately following the output is *not* the prompt; you can clearly see the actual prompt on the following line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have output text without telling the terminal to move the cursor to the start of the next time.

Rather than displaying a prompt on the same line as other text, zsh moves the cursor to the next line after outputting `%` to indicate it has done so.

To move the cursor as you should, replace

```c
printf("%s", buf);
```

with

```c
printf("%s\n", buf);
```

Comment: `buf` is not null-terminated, and it is quite critical point.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wrong post. I'm not the OP. The bug in question is not even copied into my answer.

Comment: I think this should be pointed out in an answer, especially an accepted one.

Comment: [Why ZSH ends a line with a highlighted percent symbol?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/167582) on Unix.SE explains more detail about the ZSH side of things, including what it actually writes to the terminal to arrange for that (enough spaces to line-wrap if the cursor was anywhere except the start of a line).

Answer (score 5):

I found this comment on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/er6fok/getting_sign_in_output/ff2im4f/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

> Zsh has a nice feature where it can tell you whether the previous
> command did or didn't have a trailing newline. You can customize what
> gets printed in this case. I have this option in my ~/.zshrc:
>
> PROMPT_EOL_MARK='%K{red} ' This will print a red block instead of
> inverted % (or inverted # when you are root). I find it nicer.
>
> You can also set this parameter to empty.
>
> PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''

Comment: Also, the shell options `PROMPT_CR` and `PROMPT_SP` can be used to control if such a mark is output or not.